# Can @GET define Consumes Content-Type for JAX-RS implementation?

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey, jax-rs

I have been trying few samples on JAXRS (used Jersey for this example). The following is a sample stub implemenatation I have:

```
    @Path("stubservice")
public class StubImpl
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getString(@QueryParam("first")
    int first, @QueryParam("second")
    int second)
    {
        return "first: " + first + " second: " + second;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getSize(@QueryParam("size")
                              int size,
                              @Context
                              HttpHeaders headers)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson("something else");
    }
}
```

Without `getSize` method having `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in its definition, this class is having errors during initialization. But with it, `StubImpl` class initializes correctly and serves the requests based on whether the incoming requests have their `Content-Type` as `application/json`.

Error during initialization:

`SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Producing media type conflict. The resource methods public java.lang.String StubImpl.getString(int,int) and public java.lang.String StubImpl.getSize(int,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) can produce the same media type`

As I understand, @GET requests would never need `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` as it is meant for the content type in the body (and GET method doesn't have body).

Is the existing behavior expected ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange... What kind of error do you get? Does it probably relate to the parameter `HttpHeaders` marked with `@Context` annotation?

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for the reply. updated error info

Comment: Did anyone notice this issue ?

Comment: it is either a jersey bug or a jax-rs specification bug. i. e. it should give the same error even with the `@Consumes` but it isn't. report it on the jersey jira - they are pretty responsive.

Comment: @randomstring I was looking for an answer the lines you predicted (thought the committor of Jersey might respond). Thank you anyway

Comment: happy to be of help. not adding a formal answer because it is not confirmed and wouldn't be worth it. thanks for pointing out the probable bug and for putting a bounty on it! =)

Answer (score 7):

Not a JAX-RS expert at all, so this is just a guess.

How could Jersey decide which method to invoke when a GET request comes in if you don't set `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`?

Both methods answer to GET requests, on the same path, accept any media type, and produce the same media type. So my guess is that Jersey can't decide (other than randomly) which method to call when a GET request comes in to this path, and thus refuses to start up.

The `@Consumes` annotation makes it call getSize when request has a JSON body (i.e. never), and the other method in all the other cases (i.e. always).

Comment: I think this is a wrong guess. Jersey can decide based on the `Accept:` header and if that is missing there is a priority order to which encodings to serve. From that order it finds the method annotated with the correct `@Produces`.

Comment: @randomstring: precisely. But since both methods have the same `Produces` annotation, it can't decide which one to call.

Comment: correct re same `Produces` but what i meant about the guess being wrong is your guess that `@Consumes` is used to disambiguate. since `GET` has no body why would Jersey even bother to look at `@Consumes` unless it was for removing dead code which shouldn't be there in the first case. So the ambiguity would remain regardless of the `@Consumes` annotation.

Comment: Well, the OP's question shows that the amiguity doesn't remain. See trevgiddy's answer below.

Comment: i'd bet the behavior described by the OP is implementation dependent. Jersey being the first reference implementation racing to the Java EE schedule didn't bother ignoring `@Consumes` applied to `@GET` and accordingly is giving a "false negative" - i. e. it should give the same initialization error but it is not either due to a bug or due to implementation-defined behavior due to a spec bug

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set Path for neither getString nor getSize. This is the root cause.

```
   @Path("stubservice")
public class StubImpl
    @GET
    @Path("getstring")   //the full path will be /stubservice/getstring
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getString(@QueryParam("first")
    int first, @QueryParam("second")
    int second)
    {
        return "first: " + first + " second: " + second;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getsize")    //the full path will be /stubservice/getsize
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getSize(@QueryParam("size")
                              int size,
                              @Context
                              HttpHeaders headers)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson("something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about having the same path for two `@GET` methods. I understand that if the `@Path` is different it would not cause any problems

Comment: If the goal is to define both methods with the same HTTP word (GET) and the same URI path (/), how do you expect JERSEY would make a difference between them ? I mean, from the caller's point of view, what would you provide in the http request that would be different ? Knowing that query params do not count. Morover, providing "body" content in a GET is not expected in the REST architectural pattern.

Comment: @zim2001 I understand that Jersey expected to error out when there is no difference in their annotated definition. However, the question was about `@Consumes` definition affecting the implemenation

Comment: I didn't catch correctly your question so far. If i'm correct, your question could be rewritten "Isn't there a missing control in JERSEY that should make it throw the same exception in this situation, no matter potential @Consumes on GETs ?". I would answer yes.

Answer (score 0):

To start off with the error that you are getting on initialization:

The reason that you are getting the error is as `@Stony Zhang` suggests. When you remove the `@Consumes`, both of the methods are essentially pointing to the same path, and JAX-RS has no way of distinguishing between the two RESTFul endpoints.

The `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` is not needed by the GET request. From the oracle documentation at [@Consumes oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html#gipzh)  
The @Consumes annotation is used to specify which MIME media types of representations a resource can accept, or consume, from the client. This means that you indeed, do not need to use json as the media type that the endpoint is going to accept. You can use @Consumes("multipart/related") or @Consumes({"text/plain,text/html"}) or whatever, depending on what MIME type you are sending to the server.

You are also correct in saying that @GET does not have a body. This is placed in the @Path annontation and is the querystring input from the url. It is something like

```
`@GET

 @Path("/stubservice/{id}")`
```